# $d(K,\partial U)=\inf\{d(K,\partial U_{\alpha}):\alpha\in A\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ be a family of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $U$ be a connected component of $$\mathrm{int}\left(\bigcap_{\lambda\in A}U_{\alpha}\right)$$ and $K\subset U$ a compact set. How to prove that  $$d(K,\partial U)=\inf_{\alpha\in A}d(K,\partial U_{\alpha})$$

---

Notice that $d(K,\partial U)\le d(K,\partial U_{\alpha})$ then $d(K,\partial U)\le\inf_{\alpha\in A}d(K,\partial U_{\alpha})$

$d(K,\partial U)=\inf\{||a-b||:a\in K,b\in\partial U\}$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: If $r < \inf \{ d(K,\partial U_\alpha) : \alpha \in A\}$, what does that say about $B_r(K)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d(K,U)$ is the supremum of all $r$ such that the $r$-neighborhood of $K$ is contained in $U$. Let the set of such $r$ be called $R(U)$.

A set is contained in $U$ if and only if it is contained in $U_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$. Thus, $R(U)=\bigcap R(U_\alpha)$.

The supremum of intersection is the infimum of suprema.